# Why does my cron job not work?

Tags: cron

I read trough 20 questions regarding cron jobs and what not you need to set and I did all that, don't tag this as a duplicate. So my script is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

openRTSP_process_ids=(`/bin/ps -fu $USER | /bin/grep "openRTSP" | /bin/grep -v "grep" | /bin/grep -v $0 | /usr/bin/awk '{print $2}'`)
echo $openRTSP_process_ids
for i in "${openRTSP_process_ids[@]}"
do
    if [ -n "$i" ]; then
        echo $i
        kill -1 $i
    fi
done
```

and my crontab looks like this:

```
#SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/home/username/bin:/home/username/.local/bin:/opt/OpenPrinting-Gutenprint/sbin:/opt/OpenPrinting-Gutenprint/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap$

43,41,26,21,16,12,1,7,48,46,33,49,54,57,59,4,9,14,19,24,27,29,32,34,39,44 * * * * bash /home/username/Documents/stop_openRTSP &>> /home/username/stop.log
50,55,0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45 * * * * /home/username/Documents/start_openRTSP
```

I tried it with the standard sh shell and the bash shell both doesn't work. I tried redirecting the output to a log file bot using &>> bash redirection and 2>&1 sh redirection, but the log file is just empty. I tried a bunch of things but the proccess never get killed, but they do when I do it via command line.

Additionally to adding path and shell I wrote all commands with their full path. I check if it worked by looking at ps aux | grep openRTPS and looking at the processes open. When I run the script from command line the processes get closed but via cron job they just stay open.

In some versions I had a touch bla at the beginning so I do know that this specific scrip IS getting executed but not all commands.

Comment: Are you sure your `cron` environment sets `$USER`?

Comment: Add `set -x` to the top of your scripts, and then review the log files to ensure that they're doing what you think they're doing.

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOMYYYYY GOD. How could I have missed that for about 2h. Damn, thank you it's working :D Today was a too long day.

Comment: Can I close my own question? Or do I just delete it now?

Comment: That extensive `ps ...` line might be readily replaced with a `pgrep` call.

Comment: If @DopeGhoti does not post his suggestion as an answer, it would be helpful to future visitors of the site if you posted his suggestion and your actions as an answer, then indicate it as the answer that worked. Thus we get a valid question with correct answer for the site archive. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the whole script could mostly be replaced by one call to `pkill`.

Comment: Glad to hear I put you on the path to a solution; I've expanded on my above comment in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If jobs or scripts are not doing what you expect them to, one very helpful troubleshooting tip is to add `set -x` to the top of the script, and inspect the output to ensure that the script is doing what you *think* it's doing.  It's quite possible you're making some assumptions or presumptions of your runtime environment which are not borne out in the field.